# Why doesn't progressbar in CollectionViewCell update? Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, progress-bar, avplayer

So i have been trying to update the progressbar when the audio is playing. So when you tap on a play button the audio starts playing and the progressbar should start updating but it doesn't! Nothing happens and the progress stays at 0.

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, HomeCollectionCellDelegate {

    func didPlayButtonPressed(cell: HomeCollectionViewCell) {

        if let indexPath = collectionView.indexPathForCell(cell) {
  if isPlayingAudio == false {
  audioPlayer = AVPlayer(URL: NSURL(string: posts[indexPath.row].audioFile.url!)!)
            self.audioPlayer.play()
  isPlayingAudio = true
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
                self.doTimeConsumingWork(cell)
            }
   }
 }
  var percentage: Float = 0
    var currentCounter: Float = 0

    func doTimeConsumingWork(cell: HomeCollectionViewCell) {
        if let indexPath = collectionView.indexPathForCell(cell) {
        var duration = Float(CMTimeGetSeconds((audioPlayer.currentItem?.duration)!))
        var currentTime = Float(CMTimeGetSeconds((audioPlayer.currentItem?.currentTime())!))

        while currentCounter < duration {

             var x = currentTime / duration
            currentCounter += x
            percentage = Float(currentCounter) / Float(duration)

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

                   // self.updateProgressBar(cell)
                    self.setProgressAtIndex(indexPath.row, withProgress: self.percentage/100.0)
                }



        //Finished doing time consuming work
            cell.progressBar.setProgress(0.0, animated: true)}

    }
    }
 func setProgressAtIndex(index: NSInteger, withProgress progress: Float) {

        if let cell: HomeCollectionViewCell = self.collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: index, inSection: 0)) as! HomeCollectionViewCell {
            cell.progressBar.setProgress(progress, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Two errors: you set setProgress(0.0, animated: true) in the while loop. And: this has to be done on the main queue.

Comment: Thanks for responding! How do i do this on the main queue exactly? Sorry i'm new to swift.

Comment: With dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) But do not set it to 0.0, makes no sense, hm?

Comment: Am i not already doing that in the doTimeConsumingWork function? Or do you mean when calling that function in didPlayButtonPressed method instead of dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0))?

Comment: doTimeConsumingWork is executed on the global queue - you are not allowed to update UI on a global queue, just on the main queue.

Comment: setProgressAtIndex updates UI and is executed in the main queue - that's fine. Try to remove cell.progressBar.setProgress in doTimeConsumingWork func.

Comment: I did it, but the progressbar still doesn't update.

Comment: Put a print(progress) in setProgressAtIndex. What do you see?

Comment: It prints nothing, i than wrote print("test") in the viewDidLoad and it did print that.

Comment: Put prints everywhere and see what is called and what not.

Comment: Okay, so i put a print inside the didPlayButtonPressed method and it actually printed it. I also put a print inside the doTimeConsumingWork function and it didn't print that

Comment: In didPlayButtonPressed: put a print after every if and see what is called.

Comment: All prints get printed

Comment: Should i maybe do everything in the didPlayButtonPressed instead of calling functions?

Comment: I put a print inside the while loop and it doesn't print, so the problem is there i think?

Comment: Just go on, you'r on the right track...

Comment: Alright i solved it, too much to comment on here tho. Thank you for helping me!

Comment: Great. To confuse you a little more :) : don't do the while loop for updating the UI. One iteration is around some nanoseconds, there is no need to update the UI that often. Better is some kind of timer which updates the UI every 50ms or so.

Comment: But thanks for helping out tho, i really learned a lot.

Comment: I actually used animateWithDuration here